# ReactJS and Redux. How to highlight currently clicked element?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

### For changing states I use redux. I have ChapterList Component where i iterate the list of chapters and display it , also I have Content Component where the content itself is displayed

On the left side i have list of topics, when I click on one of them,this topic's content is displayed on the right side. How to make also the topic from the left to be highlighted.

[image: On the left side i have list of topics, when I click on one of them,this topic's content is displayed on the right side. How to make also the topic from the left to be highlighted]

I want it to be highlighted like here.

[image: I want it to look like here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your topic is a separate component, so you can pass 'isActive' prop to it and then in render function check for 'isActive' prop and add an 'active' class.

in Topic component:

```
render() {
  const classes = this.props.isActive ? 'topic topic-active' : 'topic';
  return ( 
    <div className={classes} >
  ...
```